# How can I preview the output of a RNW file?

Tags: r, rstudio

I currently create pdfs in RStudio by calling the knit2pdf function on a RNW file. However, when playing around with the LaTeX formatting in the RNW file, I'm wondering how I can preview my results? Running the lines in RStudio does not work and compilepdf doesn't seem to work either on the minimal, complete chunks of code I'm testing with, ex.

```
\marginpar{\vspace{2mm}\small{\textsc{Contents\\[2mm]}}
\scriptsize\tabcolsep=0.1cm
\begin{tabular}{ m{4.5cm} l}
\hyperlink{page.1}{Overview} & pg. 1\\[1mm]
\hyperlink{page.2}{Summary} & pg. 2\\[1mm]
\end{tabular}\\[3mm]}
```

Please help me be able to ask better questions on this site!

Comment: Most TeX editors don't provide code fragment preview (and RStudio certainly doesn't), so I don't think there's a simple way to do this from RStudio at all.

Comment: And just to preempt people on the site who will ask for a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), although it *is* very important to post such an example when you ask specific questions on the site (including sample R code if necessary), in this particular case, since you are asking about how to compile fragments, a MWE will not help. :)

Comment: the question is I suspect more about R than TeX, but to comment on the tex posted `\small` does not take an argument so the `{..}` around contents are not doing anything, and never end a paragraph with `\\ ` so the final `\\ ` is wrong. as it is just a fragment it is hard to say but it is rather fragile and unusual to have fixed references to page numbers in a latex document rather than using `\pageref` so they work if later edits mean those items appear on differently numbered pages.